# JBoss 'update resource' option in Intellij does not update my xhtml file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

I'm front end developer in new team and as the only person I have following problem: after I do any change to xhtml file and I run option 'Update resources', the changes are not visible after browser refresh.

[image]

Above you can find the configuration. I found I can edit xhtml files directly in ear's target folder.

[image]

But is not very convenient and proper way to do it. All my friends can press just update resources and they have the changes immediately, so for some reason files are not replaced with new changes in ear's target folder. I think it can be something with cashing but I'm very bad with Java stuff. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Is it reproducible with some new sample project?